# Breaking out of for loop in batch file when using goto

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a program for each line in a file. I am triggering four instances at a time. After four instances, waiting for some time and triggering another one. After wait time batch script is breaking.

Please suggest if I'm doing wrong.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%J in ( %JobListFile% ) do (
    SET JobName=%%J
    echo job name !JobName!

    if "!JobName!" equ "" (
        echo joblist not found... rerun the script..
        REM exit /b
    ) else (
        :waittofinish
        for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ( 'tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq dsexport.exe" ^| grep -c "dsexport.exe"' ) do ( SET /A CurrInstances=%%a )
        echo current instance is !CurrInstances!
        echo parallelism set to !NoOfParallelInstances!
        if "!CurrInstances!" gtr "!NoOfParallelInstances!" (
            echo going to wait
            sleep 5
            goto waittofinish
            echo failed to go wait label...
        ) else (
            echo Exporting job:   !JobName! ...............Starting
            start /b cmd /C "C:/IBM/9.1/InformationServer/Clients/Classic/dsexport.exe /D=%vDomain% /U=%vuserID% /P=%vpassword% /H=%vServer% %vDSProject% /NODEPENDENTS /JOB=!JobName! %tmppath%\!JobName!.dsx"
            echo.
            echo.
        )
    )

)

echo script completed...

exit /b
```

Comment: do not use `goto` or labels within a block (a block is all between `(` and `)`), unless you intentionally want to leave the block.

Comment: You can put the entire block starting at `:waittofinish` (so the entire code in the `else` clause of `if "!JobName!" equ ""`) into a sub-routine and use `call`; that way you hide the `goto` from the context of the `for /F %%J` loop...

Comment: Thanks Aschipfl. It worked. you saved me... But is anything im missing? last line is executing twice? I mean for last line in the file, program is executing two times.. any idea on this? sub-routine is triggering the program second time. how to prevent it?

Comment: Fixed it. I created one more sub routine for the main loop and placed EOF command at the end for each sub routines. Thanks again aschipfl, for your suggestion and editing my post for clean look and feel...

Answer (score 1):

`goto :Label` breaks the block context of a code block in parentheses `( ... )`; this is also true for `for ... do ( ... )` loops and `if ... ( ... ) else ( ... )` conditions.

To overcome this, you can put the code portion with `goto` and `:Label` into a subroutine, because this hides the block context of the calling code portion from `goto`, like this:

```dos
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%J in ( "%JobListFile%" ) do (
    SET "JobName=%%J"
    echo job name !JobName!

    if "!JobName!" equ "" (
        echo joblist not found... rerun the script..
        REM exit /b
    ) else (
        rem /* The `goto` and `:Label` code fragment has been transferred to a subroutine,
        rem    which receives the current value of variable `JobName` as an argument: */
        call :waittofinish "!JobName!"
    )

)

echo script completed...

exit /b


:waittofinish  JobName
rem // This subroutine contains the `goto` and `:Label` code fragment so that it does no longer appear inside of a block `( ... )`:
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ( 'tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq dsexport.exe" ^| grep -c "dsexport.exe"' ) do ( SET /A CurrInstances=%%a )
echo current instance is !CurrInstances!
echo parallelism set to !NoOfParallelInstances!
if "!CurrInstances!" gtr "!NoOfParallelInstances!" (
    echo going to wait
    sleep 5
    goto :waittofinish
    echo failed to go wait label...
) else (
    echo Exporting job:   %~1 ...............Starting
    rem // Not sure if some arguments should be enclosed in `""` in the next line (but I do not know `dsexport.exe`):
    start "" /b cmd /C "C:/IBM/9.1/InformationServer/Clients/Classic/dsexport.exe /D=%vDomain% /U=%vuserID% /P=%vpassword% /H=%vServer% %vDSProject% /NODEPENDENTS /JOB=%~1 %tmppath%\%~1.dsx"
    echo.
    echo.
)
exit /b
```

N. B.: I didn't check the logic of your script, because I don't have/know `grep.exe` or `dsexport.exe`.